# Ajax no logra pasar un atributo text de sql

Tags: php, sql, ajax

**EDIT:** He estado investigando y el problema subyace en los caracteres especiales. Si los coloco como un valor estático en el código php no supone ningún problema, tampoco cuando realizo la consulta en la consola de comandos. Pero a la hora de recuperar la información sí da fallo.

Tengo el siguiente problema con mi código. Estoy pasando por ajax un dato de tipo TEXT en sql que debería imprimirse como valor en un input vacío. Con el resto de valores funciona perfectamente, pero con "longname" da problemas. 
He probado cambiando el tipo de valor en la base de datos a LONGTEXt y VARCHAR, pero no hay cambios. Tampoco es por ningún límite de caracteres del array o uso de caracteres extraños, porque probé a poner el contenido como un valor estático.
¿Alguna solución?
Gracias de antemano.

PD: Dejo a continuación parte del código para que le echéis un vistazo.

```php
$( "#nombrearcano" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "autocomplete.editararcanos.php",
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        search: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( data );
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#nombrearcano').val(ui.item.label);
                $('#nombrelargo').val(ui.item.longname);
                $('#efecto').val(ui.item.efecto);
                $('#statefecto1').val(ui.item.statefecto1);


                return false;
            }
        });



    });
```

```
include "config.php";

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $search = $_POST['search'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM ARCANOS WHERE ARCANOS.nombre like '%".$search."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
        $response[] = array("efecto"=>$row['efecto'], "statefecto1"=>$row['statefecto1'], "longname"=>$row['longname'], "label"=>$row['nombre']);
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

```html
<tr>
            <td>Arcano</td>
            <td><input type='text' id='nombrearcano' name='nombrearcano' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Efectos</td>
            <td><input type='text' id='efecto' name='efecto'></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="efecto2" name="efecto2">
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Afecta a</td>
            <td><input type='text' id='statefecto1' name='statefecto1'></td>
            <td><input type='text' id='statefecto2' name='statefecto2'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Duración</td>
            <td><input type='text' id='turnosefecto1' name='turnosefecto1'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' id='turnosefecto2' name='turnosefecto2'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Descripción/Comentario</td>
            <td><input type='text' id='comentario' name='comentario'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Descripción del arcano</td>
            <td><input type='text' id='longname' name='longname'/></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta el HTML que estás modificando

Comment: Saludos, en "autocomplete.editararcanos.php" recibe ya tu parámetro enviado por ajax "search" o no lo recibe ?

Comment: Buenas. 
Sí, recibe el parámetro, todo funciona perfecto excepto por el atributo llamado `longname`, es el único que da problemas.

Comment: @Alumnopreocupado revisa en el debug del navegador, en cualquiera que estes ocupando, la pestaña de network, y revisa que es en realidad lo que estas recibiendo como respuesta de tu consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado.

Era un error de PHP al recoger los datos de MySQL, por alguna razón codificaba los datos en una colación distinta a la que le decía. Lo arreglé con la función `mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");`

Gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones

```
type: 'post',
```

Ya no es soportado, en su lugar utiliza

```
method: 'post',
```

Eso repercute en tu PHP, ya que `type` no es soportado entonces el `method` por default es `GET` eso haría que recuperaras la variable como `$_GET['search']`
cambiando a `method`, tu código PHP funcionaría correctamente

Ahora, puedes modificar tu PHP, en lugar de hacer `$_POST['search']` lo podrás encontrar como `$_REQUEST['search']` el superarreglo `$_REQUEST` responde a ambos métodos: **GET y POST**

Es cuestión de gusto, pero para mi, la primera opción es la más limpia.

Eso debería sacarte del apuro

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, pero no me solucionó el problema.
Incluso con el type: post antes me pasaba el resto de datos del array, pero conforme le meto "longname" peta y ya no funciona.

Comment: Y por que estás usando LONGNAME y no VARCHAR? que motor de DB usas?

Comment: "longname" es el nombre del atributo, el atributo es un VARCHAR(60000), aunque también probé definiéndolo como TEXT, LONGTEXT y CHAR.
Estoy utilizando Mysql, y la consulta en consola sí que me saca el resultado, solo falla cuando intento pasar el atributo por ajax.

Comment: quita el `dataType` y prueba

Comment: Sin el `dataType`  no funciona nada, ni siquiera el autocompletar.